# How can I approach this limit?

Tags: calculus

> How can I approach this limit?
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left( \frac{2^{n-1} \cdot n^{2016}}{3^n} \right)$$

I've tried some methods, like L'Hôpital's rule or the Stolz Cesaro theorem, but I don't know how to continue. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n\cdot n^{2016}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\dfrac{n^{2016}}{(3/2)^n}\to 0$$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply by $2$, it is enough to calculate

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{2^n \cdot n^{2016}}{3^n}$$

Now this can be written as

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (\frac{2}{3})^n\cdot n^{2016}$$

Let $q=\frac{2}{3}$ then it is enough to evaluate

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} q^x\cdot x^{2016} =\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x^{2016}}{(\frac{1}{q})^x}$$

Using l'hopital and a proof by induction you can show that for any $m$ we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x^m}{(\frac{1}{q})^x}=0$$

Let $f(x)=x^m$ and $g(x)=\frac{1}{q}^x$ for simplicity let $p=\frac{1}{q}$ and recall that $p>1$. For $m=0$ the claim is trivial so we jump to the induction step (assuming for $m-1$ we prove for $m$).

$f'(x) = mx^{m-1}$ while $g'(x) = p^x \cdot \ln p$.  Therefore by l'hopital

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{x^m}{p^x}= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{m}{\ln p} \frac{x^{m-1}}{p^x}$$

By induction hypothesis the right hand side is zero. This complete the proof.

Comment: I've also managed to get to this point, but I didn't know how to prove exactly that the value of the limit is 0. Thank you for the answers and support

Comment: @RaduDamian added.